# Managing imports in Scalaz7

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I am using scalaz7 in a project and sometimes I run into issues with imports. The simplest way get started is

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

but sometimes this can lead to conflicts. What I have been doing until now the following slightly painful process:

- work out a minimal example that needs the same imports as my actual code
- copy that example in a separate project
- compile it with the option `-Xprint:typer` to find out how the code looks after implicit resolution
- import the needed implicits in the original project.

Although this works, I would like to streamline it. I see that scalaz7 has much more fine-grained imports, but I do not fully understand how they are organized. For instance, I see one can do

```
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.std.AllInstances._
import scalaz.std.AllFunctions._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
import scalaz.syntax.all._
import scalaz.syntax.std.boolean._
import scalaz.syntax.std.all._
```

and so on.

> How are these sub-imports organized?

As an example, say I want to work with validations. What would I need, for instance to inject validation implicits and make the following compile?

```
3.fail[String]
```

What about making `ValidationNEL[A, B]` an instance of `Applicative`?

Comment: Did you see this already: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day13 ?

Comment: No, but it seems exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Comment: @romanb If you post it as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. (actually to comply with StackExchange policies, it would be nice if you quickly summarized the content)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This blog post explains the package structure and imports a la carte in scalaz7 in detail: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day13

For your specific examples, for 3.failure[String] you'd need:

```
import scalaz.syntax.validation._
```

Validation already has a method `ap`:

```
scala> "hello".successNel[Int] ap ((s: String) => "x"+s).successNel[Int]
res1: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Int],java.lang.String] = Success(xhello)
```

To get the <*> operator, you need this import:

```
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
```

Then you can do:

```
"hello".successNel[Int] <*> ((s: String) => "x"+s).successNel[Int]
```