# Scalaz minimal imports required to inject right and left use

Tags: scala, scalaz

Simple question, I have looked at this one already: [Managing imports in Scalaz7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358213/managing-imports-in-scalaz7), but I can't figure out how to minimally inject the `right` and `left` methods into my objects to construct instances of `\/`.

I did try:

`import syntax.ToDataOps` and other variations of `To...` such as `syntax.ToIdOps` as suggested in http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day13.

Simple example:

```
import scalaz.{\/, syntax}
import // What goes here

class Test {

    def returnEitherT(h: Int): String \/ Int = {
        h right
    }
}
```

Thanks, Jason.

===========

I solved it by using `import syntax.id._` but I'm unsure why this worked.

Comment: You should make your solution the answer - I think there are SO badges for answering your own question etc

Comment: @NoelM thanks, but in this case I'll go with Ben's answer as he understands the reason why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`syntax.id` contains syntax for "plain" values, i.e. it places no constraints on the type of the value.

In general, when you import syntax for an expression of the form `x.op`, the place to import the syntax depends on the type of `x`, because `op` needs to be a valid operation on that type.

Because `\/[A, B]` is universally quantified for A and B, using the syntax `x.left` and `x.right` places no constraints on the type of `x`. Hence, it belongs in `syntax.id`.

For a working understanding of what syntax is available where, it is worth looking at the source of some of the modules that make up the `syntax` packages. For example, contrast [`IdOps[A]`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/IdOps.scala), which has syntax for any `A`, with [`FunctorOps[F[_],A]`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/FunctorSyntax.scala), which has the requirement that `F` is a `Functor`.

---

I am not sure where the name `id` comes from exactly; perhaps it is related to the identity functor `Id`, which can be defined as `type Id[A] = A`. If you had to choose a type constraint for values usable with `syntax.id`, it would be that they are in `Id`. Being universally quantified in `A`, the operations can't know about the structure of a value of `A`, hence they can't be structure-altering operations on `A`.

Comment: This might no longer be 100% correct for latest version of Scalaz. Certainly scalaz.syntax.id.right is deprecated in favour of scalaz.syntax.either.right

Answer (score 2):

Since scalaz 7 the correct import is:

```
import scalaz.syntax.either._
```